# Android: calling BitmapFactory.decodeResource() returns null

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, bitmapfactory

Im making an app where I need to create lots of similar images made out of simple components images. The images don't change but I don't want to have to make all of the images by hand (and I think it could be useful later to have them procedurally generated). As a basic example of what I'm trying to do I have 2 drawables and am trying to combine them on a `Canvas`. The issue is that when I create the canvas like so:

```
Canvas canvas = new canvas(background);
```

The app crashes because `background` is null. I Don't understand why `background` is null.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.background);
Bitmap foreground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.foreground);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
canvas.drawBitmap(foreground,0,0,null);
```

If it's of any help this is all in a fragment.

Comment: According to the docs decodeResources returns `The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded` Does `R.drawable.background` exist? Can it be loaded and displayed directly into an XML layout file?

Comment: The drawable  `background ` can be viewed and dose not crash the app if it is loaded and used as so: `((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cube_background));`

Comment: Did you try with any other `drawable` resource in place of `background` ?

Comment: I haven't tried creating the canvas with anything other than `background` but I know that `foreground` is also null.